# Measurement uncertainty trigonometry Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and I try to plot a trajectory of a projectile with given variables (initial velocity, g) with given displacement in x-axis, and calculate the value of the initial angle (theta). However, I'm not sure where the problems lie in. My best guess is the "measurement uncertainty" of the trigonometry functions. How do I make this graph more accurate? I have also thought of changing the "measurement units" but that doesn't seem to do much.

This image shows that note 'x' was declared as 1.5332(m) but what I got was up to ~2.3(m)
[image: sample image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pyl

# Initialize variables
v, g = 4.8, 9.8
x2 = 1.5332  # Input displacement

theta = 0.5 * np.arcsin((g * x2**2) / (v**2))  # Angle from displacement 'x'

t = np.linspace(0, 5, num=10**4)  # Set 'time' as continous parameter

x1 = []
y1 = []

# get position at every point in time
for k in t:
    x = ((v * k) * np.cos(theta))
    y = ((v * k) * np.sin(theta)) - ((0.5 * g) * (k**2))
    x1.append(x)
    y1.append(y)

pyl.plot(x1, y1)  # Plot 'x' and 'y'

pyl.grid()
pyl.ylim(0, 1)
pyl.xlim(0, 3)

pyl.show()  # Display graphically
```

Comment: What is meant by input displacement?

Comment: with input 'x' you get angle 'theta'. I'm trying to minimize the problem so I let x =1.5332 which resulted arcsin(x)~pi/2

Comment: I feel the 'angle = pi/2' is a bit singular so I change the value to 'x = 1.427' and the graph still give me sth ~2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your angle calculation:

```
theta = 0.5 * np.arcsin((g * x2) / (v**2))  # Angle from displacement 'x'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its correct: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqYtNrhdDAY

Comment: You are using x2**2 instead of x2.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! Silly me I got those '2's between my eyes. Thank you. I'll make sure to re-check it before posting like this again.

Comment: No problem =), old engineering student advice: always check dimensions in the formula (x*g / v**2 is dimensionless, as it should!). cheers!!